# Python: Cannot install googletrans

Tags: python, pip, google-translate, httpx, googletrans

I try to install googletrans https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

by running this command as adviced:

```
$ pip install googletrans
```

but I always get same error both at python 3.5 and python 2.7:

```
Collecting googletrans
Using cached googletrans-3.0.0.tar.gz (17 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpx==0.13.3 (from googletrans) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpx==0.13.3 (from googletrans)
```

I tried different commands but I still cannot figure out what is wrong.
Install of httpx also fails:

```
pip install httpx
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpx
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: tried with python 3.8 and it works fine, are you able to upgrade?

Comment: thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the official pages next time: https://github.com/encode/httpx

> HTTPX requires Python 3.6+.

In other words, in order to install `googletrans`, its dependency `httpx` needs to be installed, and that can only happen if you have Python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: It's strange, because I have got python 3.6.9 and I also get this error

Answer (score 1):

for those of you who have python 3.6+ and still can not install the library, go on
[the pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/)

and there download the files manually, extract it and put it in the library file where you have installed python or anaconda. then try the pip install again.

It worked for me and I hope it does work for you too.